# gcloud beta builds triggers run - why specify branch name

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

```
gcloud beta builds triggers run <trigger_id> --branch=dev
```

Why do I need to specify branch name?
My cloud build trigger with <trigger_id> already knows which branch to read from for `source_to_build` and which branch has the `git_gile_source`

[Docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/builds/triggers/run) say I have to specify branch or sha or tag in this command. Is branch needed?

Answer (score 1):

When we create a trigger from a repository, we have to specify the `REGEX_PATTERN` :

```bash
gcloud beta builds triggers create cloud-source-repositories 
--name="my-trigger" 
--service-account="projects/my-project/serviceAccounts/my-byosa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com" 
--repo="my-repo" 
--branch-pattern=".*" 
--build-config="cloudbuild.yaml"
```

This `REGEX_PATTERN` can include multiple branches.

I am not sure but I think the `branch` param is required in the `builds triggers run` command to give the possibilty to rerun the trigger in other branches if needed.

In my opinion it is better with this behaviour and it gives more flexibility.